# Matrix Multiplication using C++

Tags: c++

(r1,c1) and (r2,c2) are number of Rows and columns of matrix a[][] and matrix b[][]
matrix c[][] is the matrix multiplication of a[][] and b[][]
The user enters the number of rows and columns of a[][] and b[][] and enters elements of both.

[this is the output given by the complete program for specific a[][], b[][]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUu3a.png)

> the expected output of the program for the same a[][] and b[][] is:
>   c[2][2]={{7,14},{17,34}}

However, I cant seem to find the error in the logic.

the following part of the code is the logic to carry out the matrix multiplication

```
for (i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < c2; j++) {
    c[i][j] = 0;
    for (k = 0; k < c1; k++) {
      c[i][j] += a[i][j] * b[k][j];
    }
  }
}
for (i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < c2; j++) {
    printf("%d ", c[i][j]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Double-check the line `c[i][j]+=a[i][j]*b[k][j];`. Compare to a definition of matrix multiplication.

Comment: You can't do this in general.  Mat Mul only works if c1 == r2.

Comment: @stark Yes, i hav used a condition check while the program takes in the rows and columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing math incorrectly.

According to mat multiplication,

[image]

```
for(i=0 ; i<r1 ; i++)
{
    for(j=0 ; j<c2 ; j++) 
    {

        c[i][j]=0; 
        for(k=0 ; k<c1 ; k++)  
        {
            c[i][j]+=a[i][j]*b[k][j];
                      //--^-- should be k 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Some strategic renaming gives

```
for(int row = 0; row < r1; row++)
{
    for(int column = 0; column < c2; column++) 
    {       
        c[row][column] = 0; 
        for(int element = 0; element < c1 ; element++)  
        {
            c[row][column] += a[row][column] * b[element][column]; 
        }
    }
}
```

where you can see more clearly that the multiplication is wrong - you're multiplying with the same element from `a` in every step.

It should be

```
c[row][column] += a[row][element] * b[element][column];
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess that this could help you to solve your problem:

```
c[i][j]+=a[i][k]*b[k][j];
```